# Error in mysqli->prepare with insert statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepare

I'm trying to figure out why my first prepare statement works just fine but my second one doesn't.  The actual INSERT INTO syntax looks correct and works when I substitute numbers and place it in a mysql console, but the prepare statement returns false.

Just to clear away the simple questions; $db_table_prefix == "uc_" and all variables are initialized.  Also, the first statement sets $results == 0 (EDIT: this was my mistake, it's really 0, not 1).

```
global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ".$db_table_prefix."attempts WHERE ((exp_m = ?) AND (exp_n = ?) AND (max_base <= ?))");
$stmt->bind_param("iii", $m, $n, $this->max_base);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($results);
$stmt->fetch();

if ($results < 1)
{ 
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$db_table_prefix."attempts (exp_m, exp_n, base_x, max_base) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("iiii", $m, $n, $x, $this->max_base);

  .....
}
```

I've included the table structure, just in case that's the issue.

```
mysql> describe uc_attempts;
+----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| exp_m    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| exp_n    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| base_x   | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| max_base | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| id       | int(11)             | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I'm sure I'm just missing something simple, but after a few days of staring at the code, I needed to ask.  Thanks in advance for the help.  Please let me know if there is any other information I should include.

Comment: On the second prepare statement it returns False.

Comment: Enable error reporting and see if it throws out an exception

Comment: `$mysqli->error` may provide more info.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /var/www/Beal/models/class.user.php on line 28

Note: Line 28 is the second bind_param line

Comment: `$mysqli->error` provides nothing, it's just empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close the first resource. I believe it can't open a second prepared statement if the first one isn't closed. I think `$mysqli->prepare( ... );` will then return false and obviously `false->bind_param( ... );` does not exist ;-) causing your `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object`-error.

```
global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ".$db_table_prefix."attempts WHERE ((exp_m = ?) AND (exp_n = ?) AND (max_base <= ?))");
$stmt->bind_param("iii", $m, $n, $this->max_base);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($results);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close(); //<-- this is the problem

if ($results < 1)
{ 
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$db_table_prefix."attempts (exp_m, exp_n, base_x, max_base) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("iiii", $m, $n, $x, $this->max_base);

  .....
}
```